# No tool tip is shown in google chrome when the button is disabled in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have a project built with angular and [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/).
I'm using [ngbTooltip](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api) to show a tooltip on a button.

```html
<button 
    class="btn btn-success"
    (click)="onSubmit()"
    [ngbTooltip]="tipContent"
    [disabled]="disabled">
    Save
</button>

<ng-template #tipContent>
    Please fill out all mandatory fields before saving
</ng-template>
```

However, when the variable `disabled` is true ie the when the button is disabled the tooltip is not showing up in Google Chrome but works in Firefox.

Recreation of the problem in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sstackoverflow-ngtooltip)

How can I show tooltip on a disabled button?

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz? The tooltip is showing for me on a disabled button.

Comment: @KurtHamilton https://stackblitz.com/edit/sstackoverflow-ngtooltip

Comment: Well in Firefox your code works.It show the tooltip. In crhome no.

Comment: @Schwarz54 This app is intended to use in google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kurt-hamilton's solution worked, but it had some issues, the tooltip was appearing inside the button, and there was some flickering.

Since bootstrap has `.disabled` class, I decided to use that.

Added `[class.disabled]="!canSave"`.

Now the code look like this:

```html
<button 
    class="btn btn-success"
    (click)="onSubmit()"
    [ngbTooltip]="tipContent"
    [class.disabled]="disabled">
    Save
</button>
```

component file:

```js
onSubmit() {
    if (!this.canSave) {
        return;
    }
    // onSubmit code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears your problem is only present in some browsers (the tooltip shows in Firefox, it doesn't in Chrome).

A global fix for this would be to wrap the button in another element and show the tooltip on the wrapper.

```html
<span [ngbTooltip]="tipContent">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [disabled]="disable">
      I've got markup and bindings in my tooltip!
  </button>
</span>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/sstackoverflow-ngtooltip-7te4bd